# Иногда теряется передаваемое в JQuery функцию значение

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend

Есть не большой участок кода с помощью которого я передаю значение `id` елемента в JQuery функцию. 
Вот верстка:

```
<div class="disF pad10 jsSBa">
    <span id="_prev" class="button-m color-blue mrR4px pager-btn"><b><<</b></span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xxx" />
    <span id="_next" class="button-m color-blue mrR4px pager-btn"><b>>></b></span>
</div>
```

А это, собственно, и сама функция:

```
$("#_current_tab").on("click", ".pager-btn", function (e) {
      console.log(e.target.id);
        $.post("/workspace/changepage", {
            count: e.target.id
        }, function (result) {
            $("#_current_tab").empty();
            $("#_current_tab").append(result);
      });
```

Так во, ситуация такова, что при клике по кнопке, на которую повешено событие, в функцию через раз (а то и больше) не приходит ни чего (`e.target.id` - пуст)

Подскажите в чем загвоздка?

Answer (score 2):

Вы попадаете по элементу `b`, у которого нет `id`. Используйте `this.id`.

```js
$(".pager-btn").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log("[",this.id,"]","[",e.target.id,"]");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="disF pad10 jsSBa">
  <span id="_prev" class="button-m color-blue mrR4px pager-btn"><b>&lt;&lt;</b></span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="xxx" />
  <span id="_next" class="button-m color-blue mrR4px pager-btn"><b>&gt;&gt;</b></span>
</div>

<div id="_current_tab"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> в функцию через раз (а то и больше) не приходит ни чего (e.target.id - пуст)

Это значит, что вы кликаете по элементу с классом `.pager-btn` в контейнере `#_current_tab` у которого атрибут `id` пустой.

Наиболее вероятная причина этого здесь

```
function (result) {
  $("#_current_tab").empty();
  $("#_current_tab").append(result);
}
```

Т.е. при завершении POST запроса вы очищаете все элементы из `#_current_tab` и добавляете те, что пришли. Скорее всего в ответе сервера `id` отсутствуют

Comment: Да в вашем ответе есть  правда. Я переделал верстку(обновил вопрос) и саму функцию так, чтоб нивилировать указанную вами причину, и это практически помогло, но проскакивание теперь не такое частое как было до этого.

Comment: До этого верстка находилась внутри блока `_current_tab` и как бы сама себя обновляла

Comment: Теперь верстка статична а обновляется лишь блок `_current_tab`, который расположен под ней.

Comment: @РоманТимохов Я откатил ваши изменения, т.к. они кардинально поменяли исходный вопрос. Если мой ответ является решением исходного вопроса, отметьте его как верный. Если у вас появились новые вопросы, задайте их отдельными топиками

Comment: Я отметил Ваш ответ как полезный, для конкретной ситуации

Answer (score 0):

В вас проблема в следующем.
У вас есть DOM типа такого:
`<span id="_prev" class="pager-btn"><b> << </b></span>`

Проблема в том, что event.target будет не `<span>` а `<b>`, так как фактически вы нажали не на span а на div.

Как это исправить:
Испрользовать `this` вместо `event.target` - он будет равен как раз тому елементу, на который был повешан listener, а не его потомок.

**ВАЖНО!** Этот прием не будет работать с lambda-функциями, [но это совсем другая история](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_this)

```
$(".pager-btn")
    .on("click", function (e) {
        var $target = $(this);
        console.log($target.attr("id"));
        $.post("/workspace/changepage", {
            count: $target.attr("id")
        }, function (result) {
            $("#_current_tab").empty();
            $("#_current_tab").append(result);
        });
    });
```

---

Так же, если кнопки пагинации будет обновлятся, можно сделать так:

```
$("body").on("click", ".pager-btn", function (e) {
        var $target = $(this);
        console.log($target.attr("id"));
        $.post("/workspace/changepage", {
            count: $target.attr("id")
        }, function (result) {
            $("#_current_tab").empty();
            $("#_current_tab").append(result);
        });
    });
```

Тогда даже когда кнопки будут добавлятся - обработчик будет все равно работать

Comment: Давид, спасибо за ответ, модераторы попросили меня переписать вопрос и открыть новый. Если Вам не сложно, оставьте ответ тут -->  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1083851/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-jquery