# Периодически не получаю параметр в функцию JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend

Есть не большой участок кода (такая себе навигация с кнопками туда-сюда) с помощью которого я передаю значение `id` елемента в JQuery функцию. 
Вот верстка:

```
<div class="disF pad10 jsSBa">
    <span id="_prev" class="button-m color-blue mrR4px pager-btn"><b><<</b></span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="xxx" />
    <span id="_next" class="button-m color-blue mrR4px pager-btn"><b>>></b></span>
</div>
```

А это, собственно, и сама функция:

```
$(".pager-btn").on("click", function (e) {
      console.log(e.target.id);
        $.post("/workspace/changepage", {
            count: e.target.id
        }, function (result) {
            $("#_current_tab").empty();
            $("#_current_tab").append(result);
      });
```

Логика работы следующая - кликнув по элементу `.pager-btn` отправляется `POST` запрос на сервер и полученный ответ добавляется в элемент `#_current_tab, предварительно очистив этот элемент.

Так вот, ситуация такова, что при клике по элементу `.pager-btn` (на который повешено событие), в функцию через раз (а то и больше) не приходит ни чего (`e.target.id` - пуст)

Подскажите в чем загвоздка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вас проблема в следующем.
У вас есть DOM типа такого:
`<span id="_prev" class="pager-btn"><b> << </b></span>`

Проблема в том, что event.target будет не `<span>` а `<b>`, так как фактически вы нажали не на span а на div.

Как это исправить:
Испрользовать `this` вместо `event.target` - он будет равен как раз тому елементу, на который был повешан listener, а не его потомок.

**ВАЖНО!** Этот прием не будет работать с lambda-функциями, [но это совсем другая история](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_this)

```
$(".pager-btn")
    .on("click", function (e) {
        var $target = $(this);
        console.log($target.attr("id"));
        $.post("/workspace/changepage", {
            count: $target.attr("id")
        }, function (result) {
            $("#_current_tab").empty();
            $("#_current_tab").append(result);
        });
    });
```

---

Так же, если кнопки пагинации будет обновлятся, можно сделать так:

```
$("body").on("click", ".pager-btn", function (e) {
        var $target = $(this);
        console.log($target.attr("id"));
        $.post("/workspace/changepage", {
            count: $target.attr("id")
        }, function (result) {
            $("#_current_tab").empty();
            $("#_current_tab").append(result);
        });
    });
```

Тогда даже когда кнопки будут добавлятся - обработчик будет все равно работать

Comment: Спасибо, вариан с `this` решил мою проблему.